# VTK Problem at producing a complete opaque volume rendering

Tags: c++, c++11, vtk

Hello,
I am currently playing around with `VTK` and its **volume rendering algorithms**.

I want to create a volume where parts are transparent, translucent and some are opaque/solid.
I tested all unstructured grid volume renderer, but for each of them, I can't get to work a complete opaque result.

My Code:

```cpp
vtkNew<vtkPiecewiseFunction> opacityTransferFunction;  
opacityTransferFunction->AddPoint(0, 1.0);
opacityTransferFunction->AddPoint(255, 1.0);

vtkNew<vtkColorTransferFunction> colorTransferFunction;
colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(255, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

vtkNew<vtkVolumeProperty> volumeProperty;
volumeProperty->ShadeOff();
volumeProperty->SetInterpolationType(0);
volumeProperty->SetColor(colorTransferFunction);
volumeProperty->SetScalarOpacity(opacityTransferFunction);

vtkNew<vtkOpenGLProjectedTetrahedraMapper> volumeMapper;
/// Adding a dataset with pointwise scalar array all set to 255
volumeMapper->SetInputData(dataset);

vtkNew<vtkVolume> volume;
volume->SetProperty(volumeProperty);
volume->SetMapper(volumeMapper);

renderer->AddVolume(volume);
```

And here a screenshot of the problem:-

[image]

As you can see that the opacity of area 1 is higher than of area 2 since there is more material to penetrate. Also, you can see lines up and right next to the label of area 1 which are behind the volume and should not be visible at all.

I would be glad if you can help me, thanks!

Comment: I found out that by setting the `volumeProperty->SetScalarOpacityUnitDistance()` to a very low value the effect decreases up to the point where it is no longer see-through. Is there any option to calculate this value based on the given grid (cell size) or do I have to do that "manually"?

Answer (score 0):

The opacityTransferFunction decides the part of image you want to render.
As the code you write, you rendered the threshold between 0 and 255 and the opacity is 1,
thus the rendered result is all opaque.
The following code may works

```
vtkNew<vtkPiecewiseFunction> opacityTransferFunction;  
opacityTransferFunction->AddPoint(0, 0.0);
opacityTransferFunction->AddPoint(50, 0.2);
opacityTransferFunction->AddPoint(150, 0.5);
opacityTransferFunction->AddPoint(255, 1.0);

vtkNew<vtkColorTransferFunction> colorTransferFunction;
colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(50, 0.0, 0.2, 0.3);
colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(150, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6);
colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(255, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```